# father-in-law = step-father?

Tags: history, kinship-terms

I've been reading *Middlemarch*, and came across a usage of *father-in-law* which, from context, must mean *step-father*. Later in the same novel, the phrase *father-in-law* was used as we would use it today. So at the time, it must have had both meanings.

When did *step-father* replace one meaning of *father-in-law*?

Comment: In which chapters?

Comment: Meanwhile, I see the OED has this citation from 1538: 'Vitricus, a father in lawe or steppefather.'

Comment: @BarrieEngland. I forger which chapter. I made a note of it as a question to ask later on the receipt I was using as a bookmark. I forgot to note down the page number or chapter. (The context was that Raffles was Rigg's stepfather.)

Comment: @Barrie if you go to google books its on page 487 (or search for father--in-law) http://books.google.ie/books/reader?id=0SJbAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [*step-*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=step-) prefix is from (13<sup>th</sup>-century) Old English *steop-*, referring to bereavement: *steopcild* was not *stepchild* as we know it today, but rather *orphan* before we acquired that word from Latin via Old French. A step-parent used to be the *adopter* of an orphan.

[*In-law*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-law) is from the same time period and refers to [Canon Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin#Alternative_canon_law_charts), which established relationships (and thus allowable marriages, etc.) on the basis of consanguinity and adoption. The two terms could presumably have been used interchangeably until *step-* lost its connotation of orphanage, which happened as late as the 20<sup>th</sup> century.

Answer (score 1):

The OED has a seventeenth century citation from one of Fletcher and Massinger’s plays illustrating the use of step-father to mean father-in-law, with the suggestion that it might have been a conscious misuse.